# Can't send or receive mails through Mdaemon remote queue

Tags: windows, email, mail-server, queue

I have a Windows Server 2003 machine with Mdaemon installed (Mdaemon points to the actual mail server `mail.****.com`). Since yesterday I have been unable to send or receive emails from/to any of the account on the LAN.

I have tried creating a new account but nothing changed. Any send messages seem stuck at the Remote Queue as well as the Local Queue is growing with spam messages.

I am using Kaspersky for Windows Workstations and in the Antivirus option of Mdaemon, i have set the Kaspersky Labs update servers as to update from. This setup was working fine until yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the problem.
The SecurityPlus plugin was expired and would not allow messages to be processed!

Answer (score 0):

Your logs will provide useful clues as to why message are getting stuck in the remote queue. To troubleshoot, locate one of the messages that were unsuccessful in the MDaemon-SMTP-Out log (located in the MDaemon/Logs directory). If you copy the Message-ID for the message in question, you can do a search for further instance of that message-ID header & follow it through the delivery steps to the point where it was held up in the queue.

And for inbound messages, check the SMTP-In log. If you do not see an instance of the message entering your system, then make sure you do not have a firewall or other device running in front of the server at the point of entry.

You can use the Alt-N Technologies support page at http://www.altn.com/Support/ for more immediate assistance.